# image Url i want to display in model window without using Streams

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a image Url which i am getting from db i want to display corresponding image in a model window without using Streams how can i do it.

```
 Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM RecordingInfo where recordingId =? " );
        List<RecordingInfo> recordingInfo = query.setInteger(0, recordingId).list();
```

Here url from db like

> D:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\sitewatcher.war\ui\UploadedImages\abc.jpg

this i want to display it as a image but i should not use streams

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need streams because the image itself is not saved in the database, just the path of the image is.

You can just do something like the pseudo code below

```
Model.setImage (ImageIO.read(new FIle("<the image path from database>")))
```